# Configuring Two Network Interfaces for Proxmox

Tags: debian-based, proxmox

I installed Proxmox on server which has two network interfaces. During installation Proxmox ask me to input IP & etc ... but only for one interface network and when I get to /etc/network/interfaces I could not assign second interface. Can any one help how to define two network interfaces in Proxmox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... after few days digging into problem, by using "apt-get install lshw", lshw help you to see hardware and about network NIC shows you which one has been claimed or configured, kinda "lshw" saved me from a lot of pain. The problem was about the NIC mapped on wrong interface ( mapped on eth1 instead of eth5) because NIC was connected to eth5.

by command in this you can see your network hardware status or NIC :

lshw -C network